# Reading BCD entries with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, bcdedit

I have to scan the BCD for a given entry in order to extract its properties. The problem is that PowerShell doesn't have any build-it Cmdlet to work with BCD.

Given a sample output like this:

```
Administrador de arranque de Windows
----------------------------------
Identificádor           {bootmgr}
device                  partition=G:
path                    \efi\boot\bootarm.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
booterrorux             Simple
default                 {default}
displayorder            {838bb5a3-712f-11e8-b4ea-001a7dda710e}
                        {default}
                        {7619dcc9-fafe-11d9-b411-000476eba25f}
bootsequence            {01de5a27-8705-40db-bad6-96fa5187d4a6}
timeout                 30
displaybootmenu         Yes
processcustomactionsfirstYes
persistbootsequence     Yes

Cargador de arranque de Windows
-----------------------------
Identificador           {311b88b5-9b30-491d-bad9-167ca3e2d417}
...
```

How could I get all the properties of a given entry in a table? the problem is bigger because some of the properties have multiple values.

Comment: Just stumbled over this article [Modify-Windows-BCD-using-Powershell](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/833655/Modify-Windows-BCD-using-Powershell) which might be interresting you.

Comment: Sadly, I've tried it and it doesn't seem to work with PowerShell 5, that is the version I'm using :(

Comment: Just to inform follow up readers, there is a related Q&A on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946956/getting-bcd-entries-with-net-powershell-or-net/50954011?noredirect=1#comment88909416_50954011

Comment: Found something relevant. 
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/6706